# How to pin an object in a tabbed layout?

Tags: android, android-tabbed-activity

I'm want a text to stay bellow my page and don't swipe and move with the sections in tabbed layout and container.
I am using Android Studio and its default tabbed activity

as shown in this picture that the red marked part is pinned and not moving through swipe:

[image: swiped]

here is the code:

activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ahmad.saberghadim.tabbed.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"

        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" /></LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment_main

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res /android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="ahmad.saberghadim.tabbed.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradientss">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ss" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:id="@+id/section_label_l"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_above="@+id/section_label"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/section_label"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:onClick="start"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:src="@drawable/start"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
package ahmad.saberghadim.tabbed;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);


        final ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);

        pb.setProgress(16);

    }

    public void start (View v){
        startActivity(new Intent("ahmad.saberghadim.kums.MainActivity"));
    }



    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            TextView textViewl = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label_l);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rl);

            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1){

                imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ss);
                textViewl.setText("خوش اومدی!");
                textView.setText("با این اپ دیگه سرگردون نباش، کافیه دنبال چیزی که می خوای بگردی");
            }if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2){
                //pb.setProgress(33);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sa);
                textView.setText("در هر لحظه با این آیکون به صفحه ی شخصی خود در سایت دانشگاه بروید");
            }
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==3){
                //pb.setProgress(50);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sb);
                textView.setText("برنامه ی آموزشی خود را بدون نیاز به صرف زمان به راحتی دریافت کنید");
            }
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==4){
                //pb.setProgress(66);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sc);
                textView.setText("در بخش تنظیمات به تنظیمات دلخواه خود بپردازید");
            }
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==5){
                //pb.setProgress(100);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sd);
                textView.setText("ما را با نظرات خود راهنمایی کنید");
            }
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==6){
                //pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_gradient);
                textView.setText("انجمن فضای مجازی و IT دانشگاه علوم پزشکی کرمانشاه");
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 6 total pages.
            return 6;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "SECTION 1";
                case 1:
                    return "SECTION 2";
                case 2:
                    return "SECTION 3";
                case 3:
                    return "SECTION 4";
                case 4:
                    return "SECTION 5";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put it outside the tabs. IIRC, that template uses `ViewPager`, so put your text below the `ViewPager`.

Comment: where is the viewpager?

Comment: @CommonsWare would you explain more please?

Comment: "where is the viewpager?" -- most likely, it would be in the layout resource used by your activity (e.g., in `setContentView()`). I do not use the Android Studio activity templates much, and so I may be mis-remembering how they are set up.

Comment: The bottom part is not part of the ViewPager. This also isn't a tabbed activity in your picture; there are no tabs, just a pager and an indicator.

Comment: @CommonsWare there is a container and I think that it is what you mean

Comment: @cricket_007 Ok so how can I make just something like the image?!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your current attempt at the XML

Comment: @CommonsWare oh I found it, THANKS

Comment: @cricket_007 editted, so now?

Comment: @cricket_007 I saved it, you didnt write any code!, please do it again

Comment: @CommonsWare now I have another question would you answer please?

Comment: @CommonsWare I have added a progressbar out of the ViewPager but now I cant control the progress when the page is swiped

Comment: @CommonsWare how can I control a progressbar's progress from inside of another View?!

Comment: And please make new posts for secondary questions. This one is about ViewPagers and their indicators. You can post again once the site lets you to ask about ProgressBars

Comment: @cricket_007 I cant ask more questions now!!! please answer now!

Comment: Can you please show the XML for the layout that contains the ViewPager?

Comment: @cricket_007 I added it now

Comment: if there are other things you need please ask, Thanks

Comment: Basically, a ProgressBar isn't what you need. I'd probably just recommend finding a library. For example, https://www.android-arsenal.com/details/1/3749...

Answer (score 0):

here is what I did :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="ahmad.saberghadim.tabbed.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:background="@drawable/bg_gradientss"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar2"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" /></LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in the mainActivity

```
mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBars);


                if(position==0){
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pb.setProgress((int) (16*positionOffset));}
                if(position==1){
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pb.setProgress((int) (16+16*positionOffset));}
                if(position==2){
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pb.setProgress((int) (33+16*positionOffset));}
                if(position==3){
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pb.setProgress((int) (50+16*positionOffset));}
                if(position==4){
                    pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pb.setProgress((int) (68+33*positionOffset));}
                Log.d("s", String.valueOf(positionOffsetPixels));
            }
```